# How to export singleton

Tags: typescript

I have this class:

```
class AppViewModel {
  setting: number = 1;
}

export = AppViewModel;
```

Then, I import the class and use it:

```
import AppViewModel = require("appViewModel");

class OrderEntry {
    appViewModel = new AppViewModel();
    doTest() {
        alert(this.appViewModel.setting);
}
```

}

This works.  However, what I want is a singleton.  So I change the export to:

```
export var instance  = new AppViewModel();
```

And change the consuming class slightly:

```
import AppViewModel = require("appViewModel");

class OrderEntry {
     appViewModel = AppViewModel;
     doTest() {
         alert(this.appViewModel.setting); //Error Here
  }
}
```

But I get a complile time error that says

```
Property setting does not exist on type.
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Works for me (TypeScript master branch). Are you using WebStorm by chance?

Comment: No, Visual Studio 13.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var instance = new AppViewModel();
export = instance;
```

As far as I can tell, Visual Studio was showing that the type was Any instead of AppViewModel.  When I changed to the above, then it started seeing it as a AppViewModel.